# Does the order of dependencies in dependencymanagement matter?

Tags: maven

In my team, we use dependencymanagement to manage hundreds of dependencies.
Now I want to adjust the order of the dependencies to make it clearer. So I am wondering: does the order of dependencies in dependencymanagement matter?

And also, does the order of plugins in pluginmanagement matter?

Comment: Which dependency management tool are you using?

Comment: @Limnic He uses Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The order does not matter as long as you don't have duplicate entries.

Comment: Thank you. That's great!  Do have an additional source for your claim (documentation, source code, etc)?